# Center reponsive image inside a div

Tags: css, html, centering, neat

I'm attempting to center an image wrapped by an anchor tag inside a div. I've attempted to use display flexbox and `justify-content:center` the image which works to an extent, but The height of the image remains the same whilst the width changes accordingly, so squashes the image as I scale down from desktop to mobile... thus losing its quality.

How can I center this  image.

Note: I'm using bourbon neat

Here's what I have

**HTML**

```
<div class="project">
  <a class="project__thumb" href="{{ project.url }}" target="_blank">
   <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}img/{{ project.thumbnail }}">
  </a>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.project{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; /*center whole block for mobile*/
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;

    a{
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    img{
        max-width: 100%; /*make image responsive*/
        height: auto; /*make image responsive*/
        border-radius: 2px;
        transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
}

@include media ($tablet){
    .main__projects{
        @include span-columns(12);
    }

    .project{
        @include span-columns(6 of 12);
        @include omega(2n);
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
}

@include media ($desktop){
    .main__projects{
        @include span-columns(12);
    }

    .project{
      @include span-columns(4 of 12);
      @include omega(3n);
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

}
```

Comment: Code seems to work fine, what is the issue?

Comment: The height of the image remains the same whilst the width changes accordingly. Causing the image to become condensed and squashed... even though I've made it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues going on here. The first issue is that you are using the wrong comments for CSS. For CSS you need to wrap comments with `/* */`. `//` is used to comment JavaScript. Because you're using Javascript comments, the `height` and `border-radius` properties of the `img` are being ignored.

The other issue is the use of `display:flex;` on the anchor tag, this will prevent the responsive image sizing from taking place. This should get you started:

```css
.project{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center whole block for mobile */
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
    .project a {
      display:inline-block;
    }  
    .project img{
        max-width: 100%; /* make image responsive */
        height: auto; /* make image responsive - THIS IS NOT NECESSARY */
        border-radius: 2px;
        transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <a class="project__thumb" href="{{ project.url }}" target="_blank">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. I initially tried text-align but it didn't work either? Why remove `height:auto`?

Comment: @samsos `auto` is the default height value. You'd only need this if some other CSS was overwriting it.

Comment: @APAD1 1 more question. What if I want to align vertically and horizontally. Surely flex option is suitable